# react-native-fs: How to read local images (Get base64 of local file)

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I have local files in my app which I read like this:

`<Image source={require("../../img/pic1.jpg") />`

How to read this file using `RNFS.readFile(filepath, "base64");`
using `RNFS.readFile("../../img/pic1.jpg", "base64");` gives me error "no such file"

Comment: RNFS reads items from the mobile device directory not from your computer directory.

Comment: @Andrew react native uses this files from the device after releasing not from my computer.

Comment: The problem is that you are giving a local path to `RNFS` you're not giving it the path that is on device.

Comment: @Andrew how can I get path on device?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`react-native-fs` will only access the files from device storage. So this problem poses a quandary. These files are bundled at build time so how can we access them in development vs production?

## My project structure

```
├── android
├── app
│   └── assets
│       └── images
└── ios
```

I store my images inside `./app/assets/images/`

## Development

When in **Development** or **debug** the files are served to the device via the metro bundler so they are not actually stored on the device. So accessing them from the devices storage would not be possible. You would have to provide some sort of *mocked* functionality for when you are developing. It is possible to use `__DEV__` to allow different functions to run depending on the environment https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment

```
if (__DEV__) {
  // do something in development
} else {
  // do something in production
}
```

## Production

From some research it does seem like it is possible to access the files in production.

### iOS

What I have discovered is that the files reside in a folder called `assets` that are in the `MainBundlePath`.

So if you want to access the following file in my local directory `./app/assets/images/image.png` you would need the following file path: `RNFS.MainBundlePath + /assets/app/assets/images/image.png` to access it on the device.

You can check to see the file path by looking at the `Packaging.log` that is generated with your `ipa`.

### Android

Android doesn't have a folder called `MainBundlePath` that is only on `iOS`. I have spent some time researching and looking at the different folders on the device but I was unable to access the images that are bundled. It would seem that they not accessible in the way that we would hope using `react-native-fs`.

## Possible solutions

#### `rn-fetch-blob`

`rn-fetch-blob` has functionality for both `ios` and `Android` to read from the assets directory

To access the files for `iOS` you would do something like this:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(fs.dirs.MainBundleDir + '/whatever/files/you/added.mp3').then( stats => {...});
```

And for `Android` you would do something like this:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(fs.asset('/whatever/files/you/added.mp3').then( stats => {...});
```

It does give this warning about the assets being compressed by Gradle.

> Gradle will compress bundled assets by default. In order to interact with asset files with this module, compression must be disabled. Please see [How to access files from assets](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#how-to-access-files-from-assets) for more detail.

This could explain why I was unable to find any assets in Android when looking using `react-native-fs`

You can read more about using `rn-fetch-blob` and its filesystem here https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-file-system

#### Storing the files in the native projects

Rather than relying on the bundler to package up the images for you and put them on the device. You could store copies of them already in the `iOS` and `Android` projects. This has the bonus that the images would be available in development, however you would storing the images multiple times and it could lead to larger application sizes.

#### Storing the images as base64

You could store the images as base64 strings in json files and then require these by your application. That would then mean that you would have them already in base64 (so the app doesn't have to do any conversion) but again you would be increasing the size of your application. If it is only a small number of images it may be the easiest option.

Comment: Notice: This won't work in iOS Simulator, there's no `assets/`in `RNFS.MainBundlePath`

Answer (score 3):

## 2021 update for using RNFS

### iOS

Andrew's suggestion for using `RNFS.MainBundlePath` still works fine.

### Android

RNFS can read files in the app asset directory with:

`RNFS.readFileAssets(filepath:string, encoding?: string)`

Encoding can be one of utf8 (default), ascii, or base64. Use base64 for reading binary files. `filepath` is the relative path to the file from the root of the assets folder.

Example if your file is directly in your assets directory:

`RNFS.readFileAssets('coolimage.png', 'base64');`

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfileassetsfilepathstring-encoding-string-promisestring

Answer (score -1):

Just using filename = **response.uri.replace('file:', '')**

The final code:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      filename = response.uri.replace('file:', '')
} else {
      filename = response.uri
}
```

Working now ...

Comment: Hi I am trying to do the same but keep getting the same error. Any chance you can share your code? I am not sure where or how you getting the response.uri? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Converting to Base64 Works

```
 const DownloadUrl = async () => {
var RNFS = require("react-native-fs");

RNFS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png",
  toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/react-native.png`,
}).promise.then(async (response: string) => {
  RNFS.readFile(
    `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/react-native.png`,
    "base64"
  ).then((base64String: any) => {
    console.log(
      "base64String===>",
      `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/react-native.png`,
      base64String
    );
  });
  console.log("response ====>", RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath, response);
});
```

};