# How can i read file at react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to read a file mp3 file at react-native like this, how can i do.

```
<Buffer 75 64 e5 be 9b 6d e4 84 97 a3 10 61 50 07 13 72 b9 ca 95 56 a0 42 4b e7 23 ea 6a 09 cb 9c 4c 3f ac 9f 70 b8 f8 56 89 d8 2e 09 79 60 42 04 d0 91 22 dd ... 52499 more bytes>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can read file by using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilefilepath-string-encoding-string-promisestring)

Install react-native-fs by

```
yarn add react-native-fs
```

**Code:**

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

const file=await RNFS.readFile(filePath);
console.log(file); // <Buffer 75 64 e5 be .....
```

Comment: @AungHtetPaing you can pass encoding type as second param https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilefilepath-string-encoding-string-promisestring

Comment: const file=await RNFS.readFile(filePath,"buffer"); i think it have not type buffer

Comment: utf8 (default), ascii, base64. Use base64 these are types which react-native-fs provides

Comment: @AungHtetPaing read file as utf8 and convert utf8 to buffer by require("buffer") library

Comment: Wow, why does this answer have no upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your type while reading from file like below also if the file is large, you should consider using `readStream` instead.

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(PATH_TO_READ, 'base64')
.then((data) => {
  // handle the data ..
})
```

Edit: I think this answer will help you in this matter

[react-native-fs: How to read local images (Get base64 of local file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578294/react-native-fs-how-to-read-local-images-get-base64-of-local-file/54594945)

Comment: Yes, You will get the base64, What is your usage so I can explain you better.

Comment: i want to decrypt buffer data and rewrite mp3 file at my app.

Comment: hi, how to convert to string?