Loading a 31mb javascript file in react native is giving error, any solutions?
I am building an app in react native without backend so i am loading a javascript data file by exporting the data like this :
export const dataArray = [
{
"field1": 1,
"field2": "text"
},
{
"field1": 2,
"field2": "text"
},
];

So the file i am loading is 31mb so when i start my app on expo go i get this error in the console

error: App\database\quotes.js: A jest worker process (pid=13648) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGTERM, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.

i need your help please, what is the solution for such an issue, is there any other way to call the file in the apps screens ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280752/how-can-i-read-file-at-react-native might help. Add the file with data to your bundled application and read it with react-native-fs.

@Bernhard by bundled you mean the app files right ? is it possible to put the file on github so when the app is on google play people can connect to the file using the app ?

Yes, you can also host the file on the internet and download it. I think the error you get is from the expo go tool chain, jest is typically used for unit testing. Not sure what could be causing the issue, maybe out of memory. Can't help with more info.
